# How to evaluate the cost of a simulation algorithm

Tags: matlab, complexity-theory, simulation, time-complexity, montecarlo

I have a Monte Carlo Markov Chain simulation to test. The system size is `n`. Now I want to know what the relationship between `n` and the cost is. In other words, I want to know the power/order of `n` in the cost, e.g., is it `n^2.5` or `n^2.8`?

Since there are many factors and steps involved, I prefer not to analyze the complexity first. I would very much like to run the simulation to obtain the machine time cost. So my question is how do I get the cost relation `n^x`, where `x` is unknown, based upon the machine time?

For example, when `n = 1000`, it takes `t_1` to run a whole sweep, which is `1000` Monte Carlo steps. When `n = 666`, it takes `t_2` to run a whole sweep, which is `666` Monte Carlo steps this time. I could obtain `t_1`, `t_2`, `t_3` for different size of `n`, then how do I check the order of the cost?

BTW, does it matter if use different computer to get the machine time? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Use tic, toc to get the times for different n (I guess you'll have to average if there is a distribution for the time for a given), and then use log to get the exponent (assuming it's of an exponential form) and do a best fit over the different n values.

Comment: @Lazarus Thank you very much. Would you please answer separately so I can make it the answer choice?

Comment: @Lazarus By averaging it, did you mean I need run k*n times for a system of n and take the average time over k?

Comment: Yes.  You're running a monte carlo, so I assume there will be some variance.  If the variance is really small, then just ignore the average part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tic, toc` to get the times for different n.  If you there is a distribution of the time for a given `n`, then get the average.

Then, if you know it has the exponential form, you can get

```
order = log(avgtime);
```

With the different order values for each of the `n` values, you'll run a best fit (possibly `polyfit`).

Comment: does it matter if I use different computer to get the machine time? Sorry for my ignorance. I guess machine time should have nothing to do with a particular computer, right?

Comment: The time will depend on the computer.  The complexity should not.  Technically, you will get some A*n^p, where p is the complexity, and A is some machine dependent constant.

Answer (score 1):

[This MathWorks article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/analyzing-your-programs-performance.html) has some general recommendations, including `timeit`, `tic`/`toc` and `cputime`.

The [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) function is often better since [it accounts for first-time run costs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/analyzing-your-programs-performance.html#bt1ltzm). However, it is slightly more complicated to run, since it takes a function handle, and optionally, the number of output arguments from the handle:

```
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
f = @() svd(X);
t = timeit(f, 3)
```

The reason why it is so handy, and accurate compared to `tic`/`toc` is because:

> `timeit` calls the specified function multiple times, and computes the median of the measurements.

The [`cputime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cputime.html) function is interesting as it will give higher numbers compared to `tic`/`toc` and `timeit` on multithreaded machines.  If you are interested in the computational burden, perhaps this is a more relevant metric. [The cputime Function vs. `tic`/`toc` and `timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/analyzing-your-programs-performance.html#bt1ltzm).

There used to be `flops` command to return the number of floating point operations, but that was [removed ages ago](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/flops/vmdd.html). If you really want to count flops, the [Lightspeed toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/) has functions for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your informative reply. I am looking into what you mentioned.